# Field information not updating?

Tags: apex, trigger

I want to update a custom field using Apex triggers. However, after "updating" it doesn't seem like it actually changes the value of the fields.

Here is my code (in Apex Execute):

```
for(Contact c:[SELECT Name, of_Loans__c, (SELECT id FROM Opportunities) FROM Contact]){
    System.debug(c.Name + ' number of loans ' + c.of_Loans__c);
if (c.Opportunities.size() == 0){
c.of_Loans__c = '0';
}
else {
    c.of_Loans__c = String.valueOf(c.Opportunities.size());
}
    System.debug(c.Name + ' number of loans after: ' + c.of_Loans__c);
}


for(Contact c:[SELECT of_Loans__c FROM Contact]){
System.debug(c.of_Loans__c);
}
```

I have the second for loop to show that the updating doesnt actually happen.
Here is the debug log showing that the field isnt actually update

```
11:02:48.16 (16333372)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0054P000009JSio|encompassit@resourceful-bear-gcntzz.com|(GMT-07:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)|GMT-07:00
11:02:48.16 (16360839)|EXECUTION_STARTED
11:02:48.16 (16368186)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|execute_anonymous_apex
11:02:48.16 (24387599)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Rose Gonzalez number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (24625896)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Rose Gonzalez number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (24670096)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Sean Forbes number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (24738286)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Sean Forbes number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (24762354)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Jack Rogers number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (24812488)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Jack Rogers number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (24834158)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Pat Stumuller number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (24878724)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Pat Stumuller number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (24899126)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Andy Young number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25051744)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Andy Young number of loans after: 5
11:02:48.16 (25092822)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Tim Barr number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25150207)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Tim Barr number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25172294)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|John Bond number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25215812)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|John Bond number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25236720)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Stella Pavlova number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25277692)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Stella Pavlova number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25297247)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Lauren Boyle number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25337711)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Lauren Boyle number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25356834)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Babara Levy number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25430754)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Babara Levy number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25460543)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Josh Davis number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25521350)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Josh Davis number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25565957)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Jane Grey number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25673866)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Jane Grey number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25724485)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Arthur Song number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25797292)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Arthur Song number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25824968)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Ashley James number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25878919)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Ashley James number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25904436)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Tom Ripley number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (25960172)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Tom Ripley number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (25983949)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Liz D'Cruz number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (26033658)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Liz D'Cruz number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (26057138)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Edna Frank number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (26106722)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Edna Frank number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (26129665)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Avi Green number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (26199571)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Avi Green number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (26224759)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Siddartha Nedaerk number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (26288134)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Siddartha Nedaerk number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (26312978)|USER_DEBUG|[2]|DEBUG|Jake Llorrac number of loans null
11:02:48.16 (26363661)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|DEBUG|Jake Llorrac number of loans after: 0
11:02:48.16 (29880489)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (29912131)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (29927576)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (29941188)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (29954685)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (29968112)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (29981454)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (29995181)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30008378)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30021756)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30035073)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30047966)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30060967)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30073983)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30087086)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30099913)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30112893)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30125862)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30138790)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30152026)|USER_DEBUG|[14]|DEBUG|null
11:02:48.16 (30220326)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|execute_anonymous_apex
11:02:48.16 (31377361)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide code and log data as text, not screenshots. Use the `{}` tool in the editor to format code. Screenshots don't work for users who require screen readers, prevent copying and pasting to compose answers, and don't work well on mobile.

Comment: thanks, good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform a DML operation for the changes to stick. That means that your code needs to keep track of the records in order to update them:

```
Contact[] contacts = [SELECT Name, (SELECT id FROM Opportunities) FROM Contact];
for(Contact c: contacts) {
  c.of_Loans__c = c.Opportunities.size()+'';
  System.debug(c.Name + ' number of loans after: ' + c.of_Loans__c);
}
// Save our changes back to the database
update contacts;
```